# Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'String?.Type'

Tags: json, swift, swifty-json

Can't solve the error below:

Code snippet:

```
func setInfo(json: JSON) {
    self.name = json["name"].string
    self.email = json["email"].string

    let image = json["picture"].dictionary
    let imageData = image?["data"]?.dictionary
    self.pictureURL = imageData?["url"]?.string
}

func resetInfo() {
    self.name = nil
    self.email = nil
    self.pictureURL = nil
```

Getting error message:

> 'Cannot assign value of type 'String?' to type 'String?.Type'

in the lines:

```
self.name = json["name"].string
self.email = json["email"].string
```

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: What language is this? It's not c#.... Please don't use irrelevant tags.

Comment: I've removed the C# tag.

Comment: Don't include code posted as a picture in your question. Include the code as text using proper code formatting.

Answer (score 1):

`name` and `email` should be declared similarly to `pictureUrl`:

```
class User {
    var name : String?
    var email : String?

    ....

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable declaration from String?.self to String?.

I can help you further, if you elaborate on why you are setting it to String?.self.